# How to make sure request hits REST api from a fixed page?

Tags: rest, security, spring-boot, spring-security, restful-authentication

I have a basic html, which contains a form. This form submission is handled by a RESTful backend api service (written in spring boot). The html page is unprotected for business reasons -any sort of authentication / login mechanism can't be applied on the HTML. How can I make sure, only the html is allowed to hit the backend APIs, and not other sources? Both the html and backend apis are under the same domain. Example - example.com/index.html; example.com/getStudentList

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make sure, only the html is allowed to hit the backend APIs, and not other sources?

If I'm understanding things correctly, you don't want consumers of your API to authenticate with the API, because reasons?  But what you want is that any client that loads the index page can access the API.

The closest implementation I can think of that would work at all like that would be to treat the API urls like a one time pad: You dynamically generate the html page, with urls that include some difficult to guess token.  When the API receives any request, it checks the token -- if there is no token, it rejects the request (403 - Forbidden).  If there is a token, it checks whether or not that token is still active; if the token is expired, then the request is rejected.  If the token is inactive, but within some grace period, you might redirect the API request to a URL with a newer token (301 - Moved Permanently).  If the token is active, then you serve the request.

Mark Seemann, while trying to solve a different problem, wrote a nice little introduction: [Avoiding Hackable URLs](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/05/01/rest-lesson-learned-avoid-hackable-urls/).

If that sounds to you like a session cookie -- well, you aren't far wrong.  To be completely honest, I suspect that the differences are subtle, and I wouldn't be surprised to discover that I exaggerate them.  The primary differences are that we are communicating things like cache invalidation and the resource lifecycle explicitly to intermediary components.  The Cookie header, on the other hand, is effectively opaque.

This answer is certainly imperfect -- anybody who happens to *guess* the currently active URL is going to be able to access the API whether they hit the index page or not.  Obscurity, rather than security.

But it might be enough to tide you over until you have reasonable requirements.

Comment: Basically the sole purpose of the html is to be loaded in client's iframe. And these api are only for the internal usage of that html. If client bypasses the html, and hits the apis directly, then theres no point of making that html in the first place. I want client to perform all the operations within that html (which was loaded as an iframe in their page). What I observed from the HTTP payload is, each time client makes valid requests through the iframe's html, the http header contains a referer field like example.com/index.html

Comment: I'm planning to capitalise this. As this will make sure that clients made the request through the html (within iframe). But came to know that referer field can easily be spoofed.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. I'm still in the phase of grasping it. Lets see if I can manage a solution utilizing what you wrote.